# How could I take inputs from a user, do math with them, then output the answer to the math? And how would I make the output value auto-update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I really have no idea how I would go about this, I'm new to HTML / js in general.

So far I have:

```
<div class="inputs">
    <label for="#arena2v2">2v2 Arena Rating:&#9;</label><input class="pvp" type="number" step="1" max="3500" min="0.0" id="arena2v2" value="0"><br />
    <label for="#arena3v3">3v3 Arena Rating:&#9;</label><input class="pvp" type="number" step="1" max="3500" min="0.0" id="arena3v3" value="0"><br />
    <label for="#rbg">RBG Rating:&#9;&#9;</label><input class="pvp" type="number" step="1" max="3500" min="0.0" id="rbg" value="0"><br />
</div>
<div style="position: relative">
    <div class="pvpThing center-align" style="position: relative;">
      Score:<br />
      <span id="score">0.000000</span>
    </div>
</span>
</div>
```

for the inputs.

For the math, I have

```
var arenascore = (arena2v2 + arena3v3) * 2
var arena = arenascore * 5
var rbgscore = rbg * 5
var score = arena + rbgscore
```

I don't know how I would make the auto-update thing. I tried a few things and none of them worked.

Comment: Are you wanting a javascript approach to this or a jquery approach to this?  Also can you elaborate on the things you have tried?

Comment: I'm fine with either approach. I've tried fixing the "score" to the span but really nothing else. Like I said I'm fairly new to this, I wouldn't know what to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it on keyup and change -- so every time the user types something the math is done

here's how i would do it :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").on("keyup change",function(){
        //user is typing so will trigger this
            var value1 ="",value2 = ""

            value1 = $("#value1").val();
            value2 = $("#value2").val();
            if(value1 != "" && value2 != "" && value1 != "undefined" && value2 != "undefined"){
                $("#score").html(value1 * value2);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter Value 1: <input type="number" id="value1"><br>

Enter Value 2: <input type="number" id="value2">

<p id="score"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

this is a basic example of how i would do this -- you can change the variables to get the correct data and give the result of the math